# Nesting multiple labels and inputs inside form tag using HtmlHelper in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I nest multiple labels and inputs inside form tag with HtmlHelper in ASP.NET MVC3?

**My code is below:**

```
public static string GenerateFormForContact(this HtmlHelper helper, string method, string action, bool includeMailTag)
{
    //form tag
    TagBuilder form = new TagBuilder("form");
    form.Attributes.Add("action", action);
    form.Attributes.Add("method", method);

    //label and input tag

    TagBuilder labelClientName = new TagBuilder("label");
    labelClientName.Attributes.Add("for", "clientName");
    TagBuilder inputClientName = new TagBuilder("input");
    inputClientName.Attributes.Add("name", "clientName");
    inputClientName.Attributes.Add("type", "text");
    inputClientName.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Your name");
    inputClientName.Attributes.Add("required", "required");

    //how to insert inside form

    TagBuilder labelEmailName = new TagBuilder("label");
    labelEmailName.Attributes.Add("for", "emailName");
    TagBuilder inputEmailName = new TagBuilder("input");
    inputEmailName.Attributes.Add("name", "emailName");
    inputEmailName.Attributes.Add("type", "email");
    inputEmailName.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Your mail");
    inputEmailName.Attributes.Add("required", "required");

    //how to insert again inside form the second label and input

    //how to insert again inside form the n-th label and input 
    return form.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
}
```

Comment: I wasn't expecting to see your question as comments in the code. Perhaps it would be more clear if you edit your question and add the questions at the top, outside of the code. You can leave the comments in the code to help people find the line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to enclose `labelEmailName`, `inputEmailName` and other elements (`TagBuilder`'s) within the already-created form or any other `TagBuilder` use [`TagBuilder.InnerHtml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder.innerhtml.aspx) Like this:

```
form.InnerHtml += labelEmailName.ToString();
form.InnerHtml += inputEmailName.ToString();
```

Comment: Doh! Where was my head ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer but a suggestion. Any reason not to use a Razor helper or Partial for this?

I wrote this in a text editor, so it probably has some incorrect methods but you get the idea:

```
@helper GenerateFormForContact(string method, string action, bool includeMailTag) {
   <form action="@action" method="@method">
      @Html.Label("some label")
      @Html.Textbox("clientName", null, new { placeholder = "Your name", required = "required" })

      @Html.Label("some label")
      <input type="email" name="emailName" placeholder="Your mail" required="required" />      
   </form>
}
```

Much cleaner IMHO. A Partial would look almost exactly the same except you'd pass in a model or use ViewData.